# Installing lights on wooden ceiling

Tags: electrical, lighting, garage

I recently moved into a new rental house. The house came with a *detached* garage. Unlike the house, the garage itself seems to have been built very poorly and neglected for a long time. There are no working lights in the garage and I'd like to install some to use it as a little  workshop/gym. The ceiling of the garage is wooden paneling nailed directly onto the rafters. Behind the paneling and between the rafters is insulation. The electrical wiring is all on the outside of the wood paneling (inside the garage in tubes, not in the attic) including (what I believe to be) the junction boxes. There is access to the attic.

Here are some images of the ceiling in the garage:
[image: Garage Ceiling 1]

[image: Garage Ceiling 2]

[image: Garage Ceiling 3]

Not knowing exactly what I was getting into, I purchased these lights at Home Depot: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-4-ft-120-Volt-3800-Lumens-White-Integrated-LED-Wraparound-Light-with-Prismatic-Lens-WR4840K30LPL/306860677. In case the link changes they are 4ft long LED light bars. It became apparent when I was reading the instructions that these lights were meant to go over a junction box that was installed inside the ceiling, not on the outside as mine are.

Should I try to make these lights work by cutting holes in the wood and installing junction boxes by the insulation on the inside of the ceiling or is there a better approach here? Can I mount the junction box next to the light somehow (I'm guessing not since that would defeat the purpose of a junction box)? Should I return them and buy different lights? If so, what kind?

If this were my property I would tear down the detached garage due to its many flaws (low ceiling height, uneven cement floors, rotting wood, etc.) and build a new one but since it is not, I'm just looking for the quickest way to get good lighting in this space. Preferably overhead lighting since I intend to be doing a lot of projects where having to move lights around would be quite problematic.

Thanks!

Comment: You can easily wire them exposed with screwed plastic or metal cable staples whatever works easier. Locate the joists if poss. You might want two of these.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, I'm a bit confused. You mean to run wires out of the junction box, staple the wires to the ceiling and run them into the lights? Then mount the actual fixture onto the ceiling joists? What do I need two of though?

Comment: Ceiling lights.... one on each side

Comment: i would run LED strip if I didn't want to install anything. You should be able to use the box though, it will just stick down a bit and look a bit off, but like you said, the whole garage is a bit off, so it might blend right in...

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75, OK gotcha. Yeah I purchased 4 of these lights for the garage.

Comment: @dandavis, use the box? What do you mean?

Comment: In my basement I just ripped out the old ballasts from two fixtures with heater type 4’ tubes x2 and new (non-heater type)  triphosphor tubes with a single quad ballast and extended the HV using household wire above the tile ceiling to the next fixture 8’ away using 2wire + gnd for the 3 wires needed to drive 2 tubes with local existing fixture earth bond.  EMI was acceptable for AM radio. These use HV for ignition.